# how to Remove PloylineOptions from google map

Tags: android, google-maps-android-api-2, polyline

I draw ploy line by polylineOptions.addAll() . but i can't remove it from     map.how to remove it?

```
 PolylineOptions lineOptions = null;
  lineOptions = new PolylineOptions();
 lineOptions.addAll(points);
                lineOptions.width(5);
                lineOptions.color(Color.RED);
```

Answer (score 0):

You just create object **Polyline** and just **remove** it, i think it will be working

```
 PolylineOptions lineOptions = null;
 lineOptions = new PolylineOptions();
 lineOptions.addAll(points);
                lineOptions.width(5);
                lineOptions.color(Color.RED);
 Polyline polyline = mGoogleMap.addPolyline(lineOptions);
 polyline.remove();
```

or clear google map

Comment: but i created the line by polylineOptions.

Comment: yes, but when you add polylineOptions to google map than it will return Polyline after remove it, got it?